# CMake doesn't link the actual object to the resulting dll

Tags: c++, cmake

I created a C++ library in visual studio and all is fine. However, I'm trying to convert the projects to CMake so I can build them on Linux as well. The library in question is implemented as pimple (I don't know if it makes any difference though) and it looks like this:

```cpp
#ifndef BLINKER_H
#define BLINKER_H

/* If we are we on Windows, we want a single define for it.*/
#if !defined(_WIN32) && (defined(__WIN32__) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__MINGW32__))
#define _WIN32
#endif /* _WIN32 */

#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_BLINKER_BUILD_DLL)
/* We are building DETECTOR as a Win32 DLL */
#define BLINKER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined(_WIN32) && defined(BLINKER_DLL)
/* We are calling DETECTOR as a Win32 DLL */
#define BLINKER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(_BLINKER_BUILD_DLL)
/* We are building DETECTOR as a shared / dynamic library */
#define BLINKER_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
/* We are building or calling DETECTOR as a static library */
#define BLINKER_API
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
typedef std::chrono::system_clock Time;

const int COUNT_VJ = 3;
const int ILS_DSM = 30;
const int ILS_DSM_EXT = 600;
const cv::Size ILF_SIZE = { 34, 26 };
const cv::Size ILF_SIZE_PROCESSED = { 41, 32 };
 
struct Info
{
    void CheckStatus()
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
};

class BlinkerImpl;

class BLINKER_API Blinker
{
public:
    Blinker(std::string path = "", std::string netPath = "");
    void main_op(cv::Mat& imgOrig, Info& inf, std::string sme = "IDLS_E5", bool show_debug_info = true);
    
    ~Blinker();

private:
    BlinkerImpl* blinker;
};


#endif // !BLINKER_H
```

This is the cmake that I have written so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(Blinker)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(D:/Codes/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/include ${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# http://dlib.net/examples/CMakeLists.txt.html
add_subdirectory(C:/Users/User/Downloads/dlib-19.21_for_cmake/dlib-19.21 C:/Users/User/Downloads/dlib-19.21_for_cmake/dlib-19.21/build)     

set(BLINKER_SRC  D:/Codes/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/include/Blinker/Blinker.cpp
)

add_library(
    Blinker_static
    ${BLINKER_SRC}
)
add_library(
    Blinker_dynamic
    SHARED
    ${BLINKER_SRC}
)

set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} dlib::dlib )
# Link
target_link_libraries(Blinker_static  ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} dlib::dlib)
target_link_libraries(Blinker_dynamic  ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} dlib::dlib)
```

When I run the cmake like this :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$(python -c 'import torch.utils; print(torch.utils.cmake_prefix_path)');D:\External Libs\Opencv3.4.10_vc14_vc15\opencv3.4" ..
```

and then open the Visual Studio project and try to build everything, the build goes on smoothly and generates 4 files:

- Blinker_dynamic.dll
- Blinker_dynamic.exp
- Blinker_dynamic.lib
- Blinker_static.lib.

However, when I try to link a test application with the `Blinker_dynamic.dll` for example, I get linker errors as if the actual Blinker implementation is no where to be found:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Blinker::main_op(class cv::Mat &,struct Info &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool)" (?main_op@Blinker@@QEAAXAEAVMat@cv@@AEAUInfo@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl test1(void)" (?test1@@YAHXZ)   Blinker_dynamic_test    D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker_Test\build\Blinker_Test.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Blinker::Blinker(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Blinker@@QEAA@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl test1(void)" (?test1@@YAHXZ)    Blinker_dynamic_test    D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker_Test\build\Blinker_Test.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Blinker::~Blinker(void)" (??1Blinker@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl test1(void)" (?test1@@YAHXZ) Blinker_dynamic_test    D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker_Test\build\Blinker_Test.obj  1   
Error   LNK1120 3 unresolved externals  Blinker_dynamic_test    D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker_Test\build\Release\Blinker_dynamic_test.exe  1
```

And when inspecting the DLL itself, you can indeed see, there is no trace of the actual `Blinker.cpp` in it.

For the reference here is the `Blinker.dll` created inside Visual Studio:

[image]

and here is the DLL created using this cmake I posted above:

[image]

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out! What am I missing here?

### Update 1

Executing the cmake with the `_BLINKER_BUILD_DLL` like this :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$(python -c 'import torch.utils; print(torch.utils.cmake_prefix_path)');D:\External Libs\Opencv3.4.10_vc14_vc15\opencv3.4" _BLINKER_BUILD_DLL ..
```

results in the following error :

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29111.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29111.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/User/Anaconda3/Library/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/Codes/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Blinker/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_3b817.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29111 for x64
      testCCompiler.c
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
      cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_3b817.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_3b817.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c : fatal error C1471:  [D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3b817.vcxproj]
    D:\Codes\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c : fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error. [D:\Codes\fac_ver\cpp\port\LibtorchPort\Blinker\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3b817.vcxproj]
      (compiler file 'd:\agent\_work\7\s\src\vctools\Compiler\Utc\src\p2\main.c', line 195)
       To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
      If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
      Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
       Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
        CL!CloseTypeServerPDB()+0x1f640
        CL!CloseTypeServerPDB()+0x1f640
        CL!InvokeCompilerPass()+0x6dc83
        CL!InvokeCompilerPass()+0xf0722
        CL!InvokeCompilerPass()+0xf06b4
        CL!CloseTypeServerPDB()+0x1f6a8
        CL!CloseTypeServerPDB()+0x1f5f8
      INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe'
          Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
          Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Codes/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Blinker/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Codes/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Blinker/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: How are you linking your test?

Comment: @StephenNewell I dont think that has a role here, as you can see the dll  here does not inlcude the actual object. anyway, here is how thats implemented : https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/5b822641

Comment: I don't see `_BLINKER_BUILD_DLL` in your cmake file. Also note that names starting with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for use by the compiler/standard library

Comment: Should I pass that?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I though it was `__` I may be wrong though! but thanks, I'll give that a try and see how it goes. really appreciate your help

Comment: Any name beginning with double underscore or a single underscore with a capital letter

Comment: @AlanBirtles , sending the `_BLINKER_BUILD_DLL` causes the cmake to error out! am I doing it right?

Comment: No, you need to add it to your cmake file

Comment: How ? could you kindly guide me where I should be looking into to get this right? I'm completely clueless here.

Comment: See the `target_compile_definitions` answer in the linked duplicate

Comment: @AlanBirtles, Thanks I'll look into in a moment

Comment: @AlanBirtles , That was it, you are God sent! thanks a quadzillion times :) 
By the way, could you also kindly guide me, how I can specify different definitions for static/dynamic builds? would a cmake if else do the trick?

Comment: Yes, i assume you've read the cmake documentation?